# TCL ternary expr does processing of output

Tags: tcl, ternary-operator, expr

It involves TCL 8.6, and is derived from answer I got on issue [Nitpicking: Tcl storing in a variable or not, for speed, in procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627925/nitpicking-tcl-storing-in-a-variable-or-not-for-speed-in-procedures)
So, consider this code:

```
proc me1 { in1 in2 } { 
   if { $in1 > $in2 } { 
      return [ k $in1 ] 
   } else { 
      return [ k2 $in2 $in1 ] 
    } 
}
proc me { in1 in2 } { 
   expr { $in1 > $in2 ? [ k $in1 ] : [ k2 $in2 $in1 ] } 
}
proc k {in1 } { 
   puts "returnal should be \"0${in1}\""
   return "0${in1}" 
}
proc k2 { in1 in2 } {
   return "01${in1}00 ${in2}"
}
```

It would appear that procs me and me1 should return the same value (they actually do, if similar code was written in Ruby or PERL). This is decidedly not the case in TCL. Consider now the output of me and m1 (remember that if k is called, the "expected return" is printed out):

```
puts [ me 23 0 ]
>returnal should be "023"
>19
puts [ me1 23 0 ]
>returnal should be "023"
>023
```

So, expr and/or the ternary are doing something "under the hood", by processing the "returnal". The question are:
1. What does it do?
2. How can it be disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, expr and/or the ternary are doing something "under the hood", by processing the "returnal". The question are:
>
> 1. What does it do?
> 2. How can it be disabled?

This isn't the ternary, but rather the general semantics of `expr`. That command is documented and defined to return a *normalised* numeric value if at all possible, and the normalisation does things like converting numeric values into decimal. For example, it would convert `023` (which looks like an octal value) into `19` (= 2×8<sup>1</sup>+3×8<sup>0</sup>).

You can't change `expr` in this area; it's a defined part of the semantics (which might be removed in a future version, but who wants to just wait around for that?). If it is a problem, you need to use the `if` command version you already have as that doesn't have the convert-to-numeric-if-possible semantics.

Comment: It also normalises from constants written as hex (`0x1234`), new-style octal (`0o1234`) and binary (`0b1010`), but you're much less likely to hit those by accident. The old style octal is supported still because changing it would be a breaking change and we're really conservative about that sort of thing, even though we utterly hate it and find it causes more problems than it is probably worth…

Comment: May I suggest a flag to disable normalizations and casting?